# Correctly read a File with FileReader

Tags: angular, filereader

So, I have an Input which returns a File. It looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">Choose File</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" (change)="readDocument($event)">
</div>
```

The File I am trying to input is a csv File.

My FileReader function looks like this:

```
  readDocument(file) {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
      console.log(fileReader.result);
    }
    fileReader.readAsText(this.file);
  }
```

However, when I choose the file, it returns following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader':
>   parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

Based on other answers here, I should be doing everything right. I just can't figure out what my problem here is. Does anyone have an Idea?

Comment: Replace `this.file` by `file`

Comment: although you are right, the parameter wasn't used correctly in my example, the error still shows after i replaced this.file by file

Comment: Sorry, I saw the obvious mistake, but not the less obvious one. Answer is coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading `this.file`. But `this.file` has nothing to do with the actual file in the change event passed to your method.

The event, that you named `file`, is not a file. It's a change event. You need to get the file out of it:

```
readDocument(fileChangeEvent: Event) {
  const file = (fileChangeEvent.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
  let fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = (e) => {
    console.log(fileReader.result);
  }
  fileReader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Comment: Your approach works perfectly. Now, is there a possibility to let the readDocument function return the results of fileReader?

Comment: Reading is asynchronous. So you can return the results as a promise or, since you're using Angular, as an Observable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57806870/571407 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this.file` by `file`.

Try also to get the value from the `target`, like this:

```
readDocument(fileChangeEvent: Event) {
  const file = (fileChangeEvent.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
  let fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = (e) => {
    console.log(fileReader.target.result);
  }
  fileReader.readAsText(file);
}
```